# Why is this BeanPostProcessor needed in addition to a UserDetailsService in this Spring 3.0 authentication example?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to understand a Spring 3.0 application which contains the following BeanPostProcessor implementation. What is this code needed for? I thought the UserDetailsService was sufficient for getting and setting the User account information.

```
@Service
public class UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor
{

    /**
     * The username parameter.
     */
    private String usernameParameter;

    /**
     * The password parameter.
     */
    private String passwordParameter;

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName)
    {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName)
    {
        if (bean instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter)
        {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) bean;
            filter.setUsernameParameter(getUsernameParameter());
            filter.setPasswordParameter(getPasswordParameter());
        }

        return bean;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the username parameter.
     * 
     * @param usernameParameter
     *         the username parameter
     */
    public final void setUsernameParameter(final String usernameParameter)
    {
        this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the username parameter.
     * 
     * @return the username parameter
     */
    public final String getUsernameParameter()
    {
        return usernameParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the password parameter.
     * 
     * @param passwordParameter
     *         the password parameter
     */
    public final void setPasswordParameter(final String passwordParameter)
    {
        this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the password parameter.
     * 
     * @return the password parameter
     */
    public final String getPasswordParameter()
    {
        return passwordParameter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `UserDetailsService` is sufficient.

This `BeanPostProcessor` changes the names of username and password parameters in login request (i.e. names of fields in login form) - these properties can't be configured via namespace configuration, and using `BeanPostProcessors`s in order to customize such properties is an ugly but quite common practice.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do you know the parameter names are being changed?

Comment: @pnut: From the documentation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html), properties of which is changed after instantiation by this postprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

This `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` method is implemented from `BeanPostProcessor` interface which automatically executes after your getter and setter methods finish executing
and once the `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` method finish execution, objects are initialized and then `postProcessAfterInitialization()` will execute.

These are something like life cycle methods.