# How to get the current set proxy settings in RestTemplate of Spring / Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The requirement in my project specifies that I need to dynamically set different proxies for my rest-template. I read these proxy values from another service and if any change is made to the proxy settings - I have to adjust my resttemplate to use these proxy settings.

This is the common code through which proxy is set for resttemplate.

```
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host,portNr);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,address);
    factory.setProxy(proxy);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

But given a resttemplate autowired in my controller - Is there a way by which I can get the proxy settings - proxyHost,proxyPort et al? This would help in debugging on whether the proxy changes made are actually injected to the rest template.

I tried something like

```
 SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();

 requestFactory.getProxy(); //However there is only setProxy here and no getProxy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a bean inside the spring container during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147324/replace-a-bean-inside-the-spring-container-during-run-time)

Comment: You can use reflection to access the private field `proxy` from `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`.